# How to bind a radgrid

Tags: telerik

i Have worked with normal gridview control,in my new project i have to use a radgrid,i am totally new to ragrid please guide me for getting started with radgrid,i have to complete the form today itself.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/simplebinding/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's same as normal grid.  it will be the same . but only differs in event name, and Some more features.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" 
            Width="97%" 
             AllowSorting="True" PageSize="15" AllowPaging="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server" Gridlines="None">
             <MasterTableView Width="100%" Summary="RadGrid table" />    
             <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

in CodeBehind Page.

```
 RadGrid1.DataSource = yourDataset;
 RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'NeedDataSource' event is nicer sometimes, depending on what your situation is and how your grid loads... You don't need the explicit DataBind() then on the grid.

Might help others out at some point..?

:)